# sql in operator with limit and offset for each element

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, limit, offset

Currently I use multiple query to have the data like that :

```
SELECT value1, value2 FROM table WHERE id=10 ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1
```

And I, now, would like to have a unique query like that :

```
SELECT value1, value2 FROM table WHERE id IN (10,12) ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 2 OFFSET 1
```

but it's kind of obvious that it won't work because of the offset parameter so I can't get anything to work properly, I thought I could use some subquery but the version of `Mysql` is `5.1.x` which doesn't allow limit or offset in subquery ...

sample data :

```
id value1 value2 date
1   64.2   10.1  2017-01-06 10:20:00
2   20.2   2.5   2017-01-06 10:19:30
2   20.3   2.4   2017-01-06 10:19:10
1   63.8   10.0  2017-01-06 10:19:00
3   20.0   9.9   2017-01-06 10:18:30
2   20.1   2.4   2017-01-06 10:18:00
3   19.9   5.0   2017-01-06 10:17:59
```

I'd like for example (for each ID I'd like to have the second to last data):

```
2   20.3   2.4   2017-01-06 10:19:10
1   63.8   10.0  2017-01-06 10:19:00
3   19.9   5.0   2017-01-06 10:17:59
```

Is it even possible?

Comment: Please show sample data and expected output.

Comment: Where's the subquery

Comment: @e4c5 I think the OP is imagining an alternative route to solve his problem, which would involve a subquery.

Comment: That explaines a lot, @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: sample data added and yes I haven't figured out any subquery yet

Comment: I haven't figured out what your logic is.  What is the logic here which explains this output?

Comment: for each ID I'd like to have the n-1 (where n represents the last row for this specific ID) data

Comment: I see it now, thanks

Comment: it's not a impossible task but what would define your last record ?? which value wise we can order to get the last record is there any `create time stamp` or `unique incremental id` column?

Comment: I used an `ORDER BY date DESC` but there's in fact an id column called `idCycle` which is incremented when a new data is inserted for this id and another column `idHistory` which is auto incremented when a new data is inserted

Comment: you can use the auto incremental column if you really want to fetch second last row for each `ID`

Comment: Create a sqlfiddle

Comment: @Suraz I might have given a poor explanation, but I don't see how I can do that for fetch the second to last row for each id in a single query (because getting the second to last for any data is simple enough)

Comment: @Mihai what would you like to have in the fiddle? The data I have, the query? ...

Comment: Just the data,so I can give it a shot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
( id INT NOT NULL
, value1 DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL
, value2 DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL
, date DATETIME NOT NULL
, PRIMARY KEY(id,date)
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1   ,64.2   ,10.1  ,'2017-01-06 10:20:00'),
(2   ,20.2   ,2.5   ,'2017-01-06 10:19:30'),
(2   ,20.3   ,2.4   ,'2017-01-06 10:19:10'),
(1   ,63.8   ,10.0  ,'2017-01-06 10:19:00'),
(3   ,20.0   ,9.9   ,'2017-01-06 10:18:30'),
(2   ,20.1   ,2.4   ,'2017-01-06 10:18:00'),
(3   ,19.9   ,5.0   ,'2017-01-06 10:17:59');
```

Here's one idea. It doesn't scale well, and only works for the specific example of '2nd highest result', so it can't be extended to a more general case:

```
SELECT x.* 
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT a.id
            , MAX(a.date) date 
         FROM my_table a 
        WHERE date NOT IN (SELECT MAX(date) FROM my_table WHERE id = a.id GROUP BY id) 
        GROUP 
           BY id
     ) y 
    ON y.date = x.date 
   AND y.id = x.id;
+----+--------+--------+---------------------+
| id | value1 | value2 | date                |
+----+--------+--------+---------------------+
|  1 |  63.80 |  10.00 | 2017-01-06 10:19:00 |
|  2 |  20.30 |   2.40 | 2017-01-06 10:19:10 |
|  3 |  19.90 |   5.00 | 2017-01-06 10:17:59 |
+----+--------+--------+---------------------+
```

Here's another idea. It scales well, and is easily extended to the more general case (so where i = 3, say):

```
SELECT id
     , value1
     , value2
     , date 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT x.*
            , CASE WHEN @prev=id THEN @i:=@i+1 ELSE @i:=1 END i
            , @prev := id prev 
         FROM my_table x
            , ( SELECT @prev:=null,@i:=0) vars ORDER BY id,date DESC ) a 
        WHERE i = 2;
+----+--------+--------+---------------------+
| id | value1 | value2 | date                |
+----+--------+--------+---------------------+
|  1 |  63.80 |  10.00 | 2017-01-06 10:19:00 |
|  2 |  20.30 |   2.40 | 2017-01-06 10:19:10 |
|  3 |  19.90 |   5.00 | 2017-01-06 10:17:59 |
+----+--------+--------+---------------------+
```

Comment: worked well. excellent answer. explain second one query working plz

Comment: What it will return, if single record exist for any id ?

Comment: Good question Suraz. Why not 'suck it and see'?

Comment: The 1st one is taking a really long time, so I'll go with the second one thanks!

Comment: It won't return any value and it's fine only if we don't wanna return any value in case of single record. Though, I appreciate and + 1 for the answer :)

Answer (score -1):

As I understand the question, you want limit and offset to be applied independently to two different subsets of your query. In most RDBMSs you would have some sort of subquery that could do this.  The main features that are used to do this in other relational database systems are window functions and common table expressions.  These are not yet supported by MySQL.

Ok so your primary problem here is that MySQL does not support window functions or common table expressions.  If either of these features were supported, there would be no problem.

Getting around this limitation is going to be ugly.  There isn't a very nice, elegant way to do it.  However, you can address this through one of two ways.

The first is to use a temporary table to build your result, and the second is to emulate common table expressions by creating views.

Comment: Or you could just use a query

Comment: isn't creating a temporary table a bit overkill (I mean it feels like it'll have to do a lot just for a few things), I may look at views it sounds interesting

Comment: As I understood the question, the issue was to get limit and offset by one id, and the same limit and offset by another query.  you cannot do this really in MySQL in a single query.

Comment: In PostgreSQL, you would use a CTE or a Window function (depending on performance considerations).  Neither of these standard features are available in MySQL however.